# Which is faster in mysql ? Multiple update queries in the same transaction, or a single query?

Tags: mysql, transactions

Which is faster? Multiple update queries in the same transaction, or a single query?

For example, in this case, which is faster?

```
UPDATE product p, productPrice pp
SET
p.name = newName, 
pp.price = pp.price * 0.8
WHERE 
p.productId = pp.productId
AND
p.productId = 1;
```

Or this:

```
Update product set p.name = newName where productId = 1;
Update productPrice set price = price * 0.8 where productId = 1;
```

Written in

```
a single transaction
```

Should a **lock** be taken into consideration?

Any difference with their **lock** in mysql?

And

Any difference between the **select queries** and **update queries** situation ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The first one is faster because the record to be updated needs to be located only once.  Also, transactions don't make database operations faster, they just make sure they are either all executed or none, in case one fails.

Locks make no sense here and the same applies for select or update statements.

Answer (score 0):

Every query will have an overhead that MySQL spends e.g. allocating and freeing memory and resources, planning the execution and so on.

So while your queries will "do" the same thing, namely *locate and update a row in the first table and then locate and update some rows in the second table*, you will have more overhead.

The overhead will usually take only a few milliseconds. But for a query like "*update a row using an index*", which usually takes only a few milliseconds, the overhead is often responsible for nearly the complete execution time of the query, since the "action" itself (finding the row and writing the new value) is incredible fast.

So even if not every part of the overhead will be required twice if you split up your queries (e.g. "*checking permissions if you are allowed to update the first table*" will only be required once in both cases), your 2nd scenario will probably take about exactly twice as long as the first query because of the relatively big chunk of time the overhead requires here.

You should always check if combining your query actually saves time though (e.g. by looking at the execution plan or just measuring it, e.g. executing it 20 times in a row to get a measurable time). Sometimes MySQL will execute queries differently than you would expect. Also your code might become less readable if you overdo it.

The situation will basically be the same for any type of query, e.g. `select`.

Since the overhead can be very relevant, MySQL has a feature to get rid of it in some situation. If you are executing the same query several times (e.g. using your `update` for several products by just replacing the product id and maybe the price factor), you can use [*prepared statements*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html), e.g. from [php](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). This allows MySQL to do some of that overhead only once (e.g. planning how to execute your query), and the following basically identical queries can reuse this.

This has not much to do with transactions though (although your 2nd scenario increases the chances for a deadlock if you would e.g. have a different transaction that first updates the price and then tries to update the product, which would arguably influence execution speed too since you would have to repeat the transaction).

Answer (score 0):

Which is faster? Multiple update queries in the same transaction, or a single query?

> > A few large queries are faster than lots of little ones. It depends on how large the table is, and the size of the data that you want to update. Executing multiple updates at once will be faster but it can also cause overhead.

Should a lock be taken into consideration?

> > Yes, check [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locks-set.html) to know about mysql locks set by SQL statements.